# App not running, not sure what the error is

Tags: java, android

I'm a student in Udacity's Android course and I'm currently working on a News Feed app. This is the error I'm receiving in my app. Not sure which part of my code to post along with it, as it isn't really clear to me what's happening yet. Clicking on any error takes me to part of files that aren't technically part of my project, so I don't want to ruin anything on accident. Any help appreciated, thank you!

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.alexaquinones.newsfeed, PID: 8977
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:151)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154)
        at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
        at com.example.alexaquinones.newsfeed.QueryUtils.makeHttpRequest(QueryUtils.java:89)
        at com.example.alexaquinones.newsfeed.QueryUtils.fetchNewsData(QueryUtils.java:47)
        at com.example.alexaquinones.newsfeed.NewsLoader.loadInBackground(NewsLoader.java:43)
        at com.example.alexaquinones.newsfeed.NewsLoader.loadInBackground(NewsLoader.java:12)
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:319)
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:73)
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:61)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
        at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:172)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:137)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105) 
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154) 
        at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26) 
        at com.example.alexaquinones.newsfeed.QueryUtils.makeHttpRequest(QueryUtils.java:89) 
        at com.example.alexaquinones.newsfeed.QueryUtils.fetchNewsData(QueryUtils.java:47) 
        at com.example.alexaquinones.newsfeed.NewsLoader.loadInBackground(NewsLoader.java:43) 
        at com.example.alexaquinones.newsfeed.NewsLoader.loadInBackground(NewsLoader.java:12) 
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:319) 
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:73) 
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:61) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method) 
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:172) 
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:137) 
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105) 
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154) 
        at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26) 
        at com.example.alexaquinones.newsfeed.QueryUtils.makeHttpRequest(QueryUtils.java:89) 
        at com.example.alexaquinones.newsfeed.QueryUtils.fetchNewsData(QueryUtils.java:47) 
        at com.example.alexaquinones.newsfeed.NewsLoader.loadInBackground(NewsLoader.java:43) 
        at com.example.alexaquinones.newsfeed.NewsLoader.loadInBackground(NewsLoader.java:12) 
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:319) 
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:73) 
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:61) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the stack say:

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing
>   INTERNET permission?

you have permissions to internet in your app?

In your manifest put this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did have the code line just with a typo within it that I didn't see until now.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in your AndroidManifest.xml inside manifest tag

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```